# Is that possible that the message comes before the netty pipeline is initialized?

Tags: netty

I have next pipeline:

```
        @Override
        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
            final ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

            if (hardTimeoutSecs > 0) {
                pipeline.addLast("H_ReadTimeout", new ReadTimeoutHandler(30));
            }
            pipeline.addLast("H_ChannelState", hardwareChannelStateHandler)
            .addLast("H_MessageDecoder", new MessageDecoder())
            .addLast("H_MessageEncoder", new MessageEncoder())
            .addLast("H_Login", hardwareLoginHandler)
            .addLast("H_NotLogged", new HardwareNotLoggedHandler())
            .addLast("H_AlreadyLogged", alreadyLoggedHandler);
        }
```

It works fine. However, sometimes in logs I see next warning:

```
12:25:01.675 DEBUG- Discarded inbound message PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, wi
dx: 186, cap: 186) that reached at the tail of the pipeline. Please check your pipe
line configuration.
```

I patched Netty in order to get more info and added to TailContext:

```
logger.debug("Reached end of the pipeline for handlers : {}.", Arrays.toString(ctx.pipeline().names().toArray()));
```

After this patch I'm getting:

```
12:25:01.675 DEBUG- Reached end of the pipeline for handlers : [H_ReadTimeout, H_ChannelState, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0].
12:25:01.675 DEBUG- Discarded inbound message PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 186, cap: 186) that reached at the tail of the pipeline. Please check your pipeline configuration.
```

You can see that message shows only 2 handlers in my pipeline `H_ReadTimeout` and `H_ChannelState`.

I do not understand - how this is possible? Does anybody has any clues?

My only suggestion is that message comes before the pipeline is initialized. Am I right?

P. S. I do not remove handlers in my code.

Netty: 4.1.16-Final.

Comment: Could there be any exception while `MessageDecoder` is constructed?